# Providing DHCP server's MAC to DHCP clients

Tags: networking, embedded-linux, dhcp

**Background info:**

I have a set of proprietary embedded-linux network devices, one of which will be configured as a DHCP server and the rest will be DHCP clients.

I need to have the client-devices only accept DHCP lease offers from the server-device, ignoring any other leases offered by other DHCP servers on the same LAN. Similarly, I need to make the server-device only serve DHCP requests to this set of clients, ignoring any other DHCP requests which may appear in an unknown network environment. Essentially, I need to be able to provide a DHCP service for my own devices in a network environment which may already have a DHCP server.

All of my devices have the same first half of the MAC address which I intend to use as a filter.

I am using udhcpc and udhcpd which are included in BusyBox and am trying to avoid adding any other DHCP client/server packages to my devices due to limited storage availability, but I am open to modifying BusyBox code.

I had no trouble implementing the DHCP server restrictions by adding an option to udhcpd.conf, which I called `chaddr_filter`, containing a wildcarded MAC address the server should check the "Client Hardware Address (chaddr)" against. This seems to be working just fine and the server ignores any DHCP requests from other devices while serving my own.

The client-side filtering turns out to be a bigger challenge, due to a lack of a "Server Hardware Address" field in a DHCP packet.

**So here's my question:**

*What's the best way to pass my server's MAC to my udhcpc client?*

Currently it looks like there are no fields or options being passed from the DHCP server that contain the server's MAC (doesn't look like I can read it from Ethernet layer). I'd like to remain standards-compliant, so I'm looking through potential DHCP Options which I may use for this purpose.

I was hoping I could use "Option 54: Server identifier", but the RFC defines it as an IP address.

I'm thinking of putting the server's MAC in either "Option 60: Class-identifier" or "Option 43: Vendor specific information", is there a reason I shouldn't do this? Is there a better field for this?

I look forward to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI I was able to achieve the desired effect by using `brctl` and `ebtables` utilities to filter packets of interest on the clients.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol)

> DHCP uses the same two ports assigned by IANA for BOOTP: destination
>   UDP port 67 for sending data to the server, and UDP port 68 for data
>   to the client. DHCP communications are connectionless in nature.

Thus, you could filter on clients the incoming packets on port 68/udp accepting only those coming from a mac address whose first half is good.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good suggestion, I do have "iptables" available, but I have not yet looked up how to use it to filter by MAC address. I will consider this as a potential option and will give it some thought.